# SSH close immediatly after Login

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, login

SSH close immediatly after Login, i can't login into ubuntu server This is a DUMP after last login.

```
    Last login: Mon Nov 12 15:36:13 2018 from SERVER

debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection to SERVER closed.
Transferred: sent 3348, received 2924 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 15421.3, received 13468.3
debug1: Exit status 254
```

This happens after I have edited the language settings 'locale' may be put a wrong locale $LANG so if this is true, what i can do?

Comment: ping the server to see if it's up!

Comment: yes it works all sites